# ItextSharp (Itext) - set custom font for paragraph

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

I am trying to set custom font to Paragraph, but I can't make it work.
I tried setting .Font= , but it only works size-wise, but it ignores font. Could you please assist?

```
Paragraph T = new Paragraph(newTempLine);
iTextSharp.text.Font contentFont = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Webdings", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
T.Font = contentFont;
myDocument.Add(T);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set it in [the constructor](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html#Paragraph%28java.lang.String,%20com.itextpdf.text.Font%29):

```
Font contentFont = FontFactory.GetFont(…);
Paragraph para = new Paragraph(newTempLine, contentFont);
```

Comment: Do you happen to have any info on why this works and `T.Font = ...` does not?

Comment: @Nenotlep I'm not really an authority on iText internals and I'd have to poke at the source or something, but I'm guessing that setting the font property only changes the font for text you add to the paragraph later. (This is based on the fact that `Paragraph` has an `add(Element)` method, so it seems to be a composite element itself.)

Comment: @Nenotlep Remember that PDF is **not** a declarative markup, it's a derivative of PostScript, an imperative drawing language optimised for rendering very large documents without having to keep them fully in memory. In order to allow for streaming output, iText also doesn't build a document representation in memory - I believe when you add an element to a document, it's usually written out immediately. So it seems like you're manipulating a logical representation of a document structure, but the streaming can leak through this abstraction.

Comment: @Nenotlep Also, just to take this out of the realm of my assumptions and educated guesses, you might want to buy and page through iText in Action if you're interested in working with PDF. I believe it goes through just enough of how the PDF format works at a low level to allow you to reason about it well when generating it using a library.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments, this is very educational an sounds logical now thinking about it. I might actually pick up the book the next time that I order something from Manning.

Answer (score 0):

Check if below works:

```
string name = "Century Gothic Bold";
if (!FontFactory.IsRegistered(name))
{
    string systemRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot");
    string path = Path.Combine(systemRoot, "fonts", @"GOTHICB.TTF");
    FontFactory.Register(path);
}

var font = FontFactory.GetFont(name, fontSize, textColor);
var paragraph = new Paragraph(text, font);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(paragraph);
var myPdfCell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
```