# How can I create a "link-looking" font with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, fonts, pdf-generation, itext

I want to use this GetFont overload:

```
GetFont(string fontname, string encoding, float size, int style, BaseColor color)
```

...which is enumerated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521515/how-can-i-set-a-pdf-paragraphs-font-using-itextsharp). However, it's not compiling when I try:

```
var linkFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9, Font.Underline, BaseColor.BLUE);
```

I get, "*The best overloaded method match for 'iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(string, float, int, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor)' has some invalid arguments*"

But which one, and why?

I also get, "*Argument 3: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'int'*"

Why does it think the third arg (Font.Underline, an "int") should be a bool? That's bool; I mean, that's not (a) bool.

Note: I get the same errs with:

```
var linkFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9.0f, Font.Underline, BaseColor.BLUE);
```

What must I do to create a font that looks like a link. I've got it working fine, with:

```
var linkFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9, BaseColor.BLUE);
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Adobe Reader", linkFont);
anchor.Reference = "http://www.adobe.com";

PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(1);
tbl.WidthPercentage = 50;
tbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
var par = new Paragraph();
par.Add(boldpart);
par.Add(ini);
par.Add(anchor);
```

...but "anchor" is just blue text, not underlined, and is thus not obviously a link/clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems.

First, you're trying to use the 5 parameter overload but are only passing 4 parameters.

Second, when you try to use `Font.Underline` you are actually using `System.Drawing.Font.Underline` and not iText's.

Unless you need to specify the encoding switch to:

```
var linkFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLUE);
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, I don't give a flip about encoding.

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct. However when trying it on my machine the Font.Underline threw an error. The only available constant for that was a Font.**UNDERLINE** in **CAPS**

```
var linkFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9.0f, Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLUE);
```

Can you check the namespace of the Font class. It looks like that is where the error is. It should be from the namespance iTextSharp.text.Font

You are using the Control.Font.Underline which is a bool and incorrect. As mentioned above use the Font class from iTextSharp.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it thinks the third argument is a bool is because `Font.Underline` is a bool!  You need to use `FontStyle.Underline`

EDIT:  FontStyle.Underline is System.Drawing.Font.Underline which is not used by iTextSharp.  It has constants defined for font styles which should be used instead:

```
  /// <summary> this is a possible style. </summary>
    public const int NORMAL        = 0;

    /// <summary> this is a possible style. </summary>
    public const int BOLD        = 1;

    /// <summary> this is a possible style. </summary>
    public const int ITALIC        = 2;

    /// <summary> this is a possible style. </summary>
    public const int UNDERLINE    = 4;

    /// <summary> this is a possible style. </summary>
    public const int STRIKETHRU    = 8;

    /// <summary> this is a possible style. </summary>
    public const int BOLDITALIC    = BOLD | ITALIC;
```

Comment: That got my hopes up, but changing "Font" to "FontStyle", I still get the 'has some invalid arguments' complaint, specifically 'cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.FontStyle' to 'int'

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - Hmmm..  Can you try casing the FontStyle to int?  `(int)FontStyle.Underline`?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - Looking at the docs for iTextSharp, it seems that maybe `Font.UNDERLINE` is needed (all caps).  Or you could try just an integer value of 4.  Here are the docs that I found:  [Docs for Font.cs in iTextSharp](https://github.com/vslavik/iTextSharp/blob/master/iTextSharp/text/Font.cs)

Comment: I've seen UNDERLINE in various places, but it doesn't compile.